# Spring boot: enforce best practices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am setting up a project and wondering if there any way to enforce repository instance access from service layer only?

Comment: You could write a unit-test and check if any class imports repository-classes that shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

We may create the Test to achieve the requirement. I have created the same in one of the projects which validate that *Services and repositories should not depend on the web layer*. You can modify the packages according to the requirements.

```
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.noClasses;

import com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaClasses;
import com.tngtech.archunit.core.importer.ClassFileImporter;
import com.tngtech.archunit.core.importer.ImportOption;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class ArchTest {

    @Test
    void servicesAndRepositoriesShouldNotDependOnWebLayer() {
        JavaClasses importedClasses = new ClassFileImporter()
            .withImportOption(ImportOption.Predefined.DO_NOT_INCLUDE_TESTS)
            .importPackages("com.learning.springboot");

        noClasses()
            .that()
            .resideInAnyPackage("com.learning.springboot.service..")
            .or()
            .resideInAnyPackage("com.learning.springboot.repository..")
            .should()
            .dependOnClassesThat()
            .resideInAnyPackage("..com.learning.springboot.web..")
            .because("Services and repositories should not depend on web layer")
            .check(importedClasses);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing unit test, can we write an annotation preprocessor for project wich enforces this even before build start?

Comment: @silentsudo, Yes, that also a good way to achieve the same. We may create a custom annotation and can create a class that extends `AbstractProcessor`. we also have to make sure that annotation processing is enabled

Answer (score 1):

Here is one interesting method IMO, although (disclaimer) I haven’t seen that someone really implements this:

Create the following maven modules:

1. Controllers
2. Services-api
3. Service-impl
4. Repos-api
5. Repos-impl
6. Spring-boot-application

All the modules but the last one will be “ordinary” jars, the last one will be JAR/WAR build with spring boot maven plugin.

Now, define the dependencies as follows:

1. Controller depends on services-api
2. Services-api includes only interfaces for services, it does not have dependencies
3. Services-impl depends on services-api and repos-api
4. Repos-Api are again only interfaces, no dependencies there
5. Repos-Impl depends on Repos-api and persistence drivers (like JDBC drivers or whatever you use)
6. Spring-boot-application contains dependencies on the Controllers module, Service-impl (that brings transitively Service-Api) and Repos-impl (that brings repo api transitively). This is a kind of wrapper that glues everything together in runtime.

So now, if you’re writing the controller (module Controllers), then you can inject only interfaces of the services, otherwise it won’t compile. You can’t inject the repositories (neither interface, nor implementations), again it won’t compile.

When you create the service (interface) - you don’t need any dependencies, dependencies between services will be supplied at the level of implementation that may depend on other services.

When you’re writing the implementation of the service - its ok to inject repository api, but not an implementation (again, it won’t compile).

If you’re using Java 9+, you might probably create the same level of separation by using their module system, with which I’m not familiar, however the core idea is simple:

Spring is a runtime framework, and my answer is an attempt to “catch” these “bad” usages at the level of compilation.

I understand that the presented separation is “too strict” and probably many teams won’t bother doing such a thing, I by myself rather “rely” on the programmers that work on the project that they “know what they do”, but I also understand that sometimes you can’t really rely on that and hence my answer :)

Comment: sir, I fully agree that this is by far the best solution :)

it ensure that you won't depend on something is not in classpath :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use public keyword when defining a repository and service class and put them together in one package. Of course you need to communicate from Controller to Service. The best way to do that is to create interface which is public (in the same package), let's say:

```
public interface UserFacade
```

which is implemented by the (same package, without public keyword):

```
@Component
class UserFacadeImpl implements UserFacade {

   private YourService service;

   void someMethod() {
       service.doSomethingWithRepository();
   }
}
```

Then you can define methods in this facade which use your service or any other services which are defined in this package. In the end, the only way to access your repository from outside the package is indirectly by the methods defined in UserFacade, so directly only services in the same package can use this repo.

Comment: I like the idea the it will not be a good idea to have service and repo in the same package.

Comment: Why? I think that there is no better place for repository than in package with all services. Why would you want to keep repository that it should be used only by services from let's say user package, outside the package?

Comment: On second thought I do see your point and it does make sense.